# Add source column in QUERY with more than one data sources

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I use the following formula to combine the data of two google sheet tabs in one sheet:

=QUERY({'yr Import'!A2:BH;'ar Import'!A2:BH},"Select * where Col1 is not null ")

I want to change the formula, that I get an additional column (after the imported data) with the source name of the data.

| Data of A2:BH | Addtional Source column |
| --- | --- |
| ... | yr Import |
| ... | ar Import |
| ... | yr Import |
| ... | yr Import |
| ... | yr Import |
| ... | ar Import |
| ... | ar Import |
| ... | ar Import |
| ... | ar Import |

I tried for exampe to add an arrayformula:

=QUERY({'yr Import'!A2:BM, ARRAYFORMULA("yr Import") ;'ar Import'!A2:BM, ARRAYFORMULA("ar Import")},"Select * where Col1 is not null")

--> This leads to an "#REF!" error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(yr,"yr Import", ar,"ar Import",
     query({{'yr Import'!A2:BH,wrapcols(yr,rows('yr Import'!A2:A),yr)};
            {'ar Import'!A2:BH,wrapcols(ar,rows('ar Import'!A2:A),ar)}},"where Col1 is not null"))
```

Comment: You are my hero! That works perfectly!